# Error al agregar al final de una lista enlazada simple no vacía

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Quiero agregar al final de una lista enlazada simple, pero mi código me respeta cuando la lista esta vacía y se rompe si lo ejecuto otra vez

```
case 6:
        system("cls");
        cout << endl << endl << "-------- Agregar al final ----------- " << endl << endl;
        nodo = new(empleado);
        cout << endl << "Dame el nombre: ";
        cin >> nodo->nombre;

        cout << endl << "Dame el código: ";
        cin >> nodo->codigo;

        cout << endl << "Dame el sueldo: ";
        cin >> nodo->sueldo;

        if (lista == NULL){
            lista = nodo;
        }
        else{
            auxLista = lista;
            while(auxLista->sig != NULL){
                auxLista2 = auxLista;
                auxLista = auxLista->sig;
            }
            auxLista2 -> sig = nodo;
        }
        nodo -> sig = NULL;
        cout << endl << "Registro agregado con éxito";

    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir datos al final de una lista enlazada, debes ir al último nodo y poner el nuevo nodo como si siguiente, tú lo que haces es quedarte con el penúltimo:

```
auxLista = lista;

while(auxLista->sig != NULL){
    auxLista2 = auxLista;     // Guardas el actual antes de anvanzarlo
    auxLista = auxLista->sig; // Avanzas al siguiente nodo
}

auxLista2 -> sig = nodo; // Aquí aún apuntamos al anterior, no al presente
```

Probablemente querías hacer algo parecido a esto:

```
auxlista = lista;

while (auxlista->sig)
    auxlista = auxlista->sig;

auxlista->sig = nodo;
```